# How to put Progress dialog in seperate class and call in every activity in android?

Tags: android

I have a progress dialog in my every activity and in every activity I write code for progress dialog with different message  where I want.Is there any way to put progress dialog code in seperate class and call that class in activity where I want to show that progress dialog.

here is my code for progress dialog:-

```
ProgressDialog m_Dialog = new ProgressDialog(CLoginScreen.this);
    m_Dialog.setMessage("Please wait while logging...");
    m_Dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    m_Dialog.setCancelable(false);
    m_Dialog.show();
```

Comment: just for 3-4 lines ?? I don't think you need to create a new class for generalizing it. It is already generalized...!!

Comment: For all this kind of common stuff you can make `Utils Class` which have all the defined `public static` functions to use it every where in your app.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define a `class` to encapsulate this operation and maybe some other involving dialogs. I use a `class` with `static` methods, something like this:

```
public class DialogsUtils {
    public static ProgressDialog showProgressDialog(Context context, String message){
        ProgressDialog m_Dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
            m_Dialog.setMessage(message);
            m_Dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            m_Dialog.setCancelable(false);
            m_Dialog.show();
            return m_Dialog;
        }

}
```

In the Activity class:

```
ProgressDialog myDialog= DialogUtils.showProgressDialog(this,"some message");
...
myDialog.dismiss();
```

Of course you can add others parameters to the operation so it can be more flexible.

Hope it helps.

Comment: but how to dismiss and show dialog using this class

Comment: making its function static isnt bad for memory stuff?

Answer (score 0):

Create a method in global class and pass activity instance like this

```
public  ProgressDialog showDailog(Context con)
{
ProgressDialog m_Dialog = new ProgressDialog(con);
m_Dialog.setMessage("Please wait while logging...");
m_Dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
m_Dialog.setCancelable(false);
    return m_Dailog; 
}
```

in activity class

```
ProgressDialog mDailog;
ABCClass obj = New ABCClass(CLoginScreen.this);
mDailog = obj.showDailog();
mDailog.show(); //you can use this line where you want to show dailog in Activity class
```